# How do I change an integer that is given by the user to a string?

Tags: java, string, integer, type-conversion

I have been working on a method for a program, and I need to change the integer in the method into a string without changing the method header.  The output of this method needs to be able to have a zero at the beginning, and the only way I can think of doing this is by a string.  I have tried various different ways, but I'm not sure how it is supposed to work if you don't have a predefined number to work with.  The internet has been no help with this so far.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

```
 public static int encrypt(int num)
  {
    int digit4 = (num + 7) % 10;
    num /= 10;
    int digit3 = (num + 7) % 10;
    num /= 10;
    int digit2 = (num + 7) % 10;
    num /= 10;
    int digit1 = (num + 7) % 10;
    num /= 10;
    return (digit3 * 1000 + digit4  * 100 + digit1 * 10 + digit2);
  }
```

Comment: I see no reason why you need to convert anything to a string here if you're taking an `int` as input and sending out another `int` as output. You just need to get the math right, but you'll need to clarify what exactly you're trying to calculate before we can help.

Comment: Something else you might want to do to clean up your program is to simplify some statements. For example, use 'num /= 10;' instead of 'num = num / 1-;'. It is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a `int` and put it inside a `String` use the method: `String.valueOf(int variable)`.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misreading the question, but it sounds like you're asking whether a method that returns an `int` as the one you describe can return an int with a leading zero.

The answer to this is: no, it can't.  If you want to present the output with a leading zero, you'll have to format it using `String.format` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're looking for (guess):

```
class Enc{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int numb = 1234;
        int n = encrypt(numb);
        String number = "0" + String.valueOf(n);
        System.out.println("0" + n);
        System.out.println("0" + encrypt(numb));
        System.out.println(number);
    }

    public static int encrypt(int num){
        int digit4 = (num + 7) % 10;
        num /= 10;
        int digit3 = (num + 7) % 10;
        num /= 10;
        int digit2 = (num + 7) % 10;
        num /= 10;
        int digit1 = (num + 7) % 10;
        num /= 10;
        return (digit3 * 1000 + digit4  * 100 + digit1 * 10 + digit2);
    }
}
```

Output for this program will be

```
0189
0189
0189
```

As you can see, there are 3 ways (maybe more) of printing the number with 0 leading, I'm not really sure this is what you want or maybe keep processing number with 0 leading.

In that case, you can:

```
int myNumber;
if(number.charAt(0) == '0'){
    myNumber = 0;
    // ... your next process
}
else{
    myNumber = Integer.parseInt(number);
    // more code here
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The method doesn't start with a known number, the number is made up by the user entering it.  The problem I have is if the user enters 1234 this method should return 0189, currently it returns 189.  It has dropped the zero it should lead with.  I can not just add a zero to every number that it makes, because then the method would not be performing the task I need it to.  I need a way to make whatever number the method spits out into a string so that it will have a zero in front, if the number happens to have a zero leading.

Comment: @user3554304 check the edit, I edited whole answer. Tell me if this is what you're looking for.